# How to export people in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, csv, export

I've installed the 'Views Data Export' beta module but unsure how to then export all 'People' as a csv file? Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new view to export. Rather than selecting content you want to set it to select users. Once you've got it as a view you will be able to export it using the data export module.

Comment: Do I need to create a page or block?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're not displaying the view anywhere but I'd go with a block so it's not placed in a site map etc. As you're just exporting it then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks. So once I've created the block, where do I go then to export the users?

Comment: I've not used the export module before but I'd imagine there is a config page for it?

Comment: OK I've installed services_views and services and there is now a services option within Structure which says the following:

Comment: Services are collections of methods available to remote applications. They are defined in modules, and may be accessed in a number of ways through server modules. Visit the Services Handbook for help and information.

All enabled services and methods are shown. Click on any method to view information or test.

Comment: OK, I've installed that now, still unsure where the option to export is though?!

Comment: Install bulk export in Chaos tools then select it in Structure.

Comment: Right, looks like im getting somewhere now. It's asking me to enter code into Users.info, Users.module and Users.views_default.inc.Firstly, the 'Users' module doesn't exist, 'User' does so does it mean in user.info, user.module and user.views_default? If so, does this go straight into the core modules folder or do I need to copy the user module to /sites/all/modules/ ? Thanks for all your help so far by the way.

Comment: Actually, am I being stupid and I need to create the 'Users' module? I'll try that now.

Comment: This is frustrating! I've added the 'Users' module then it asks me to add the 'foo' module, I've done and enabled both but when I click Export within 'Bulk Exporter' it keeps asking me to add the 'foo' module (even though I already have!)

Comment: I'm signing off for the evening but as a last ditch effort look into the Feeds module.

Comment: Still having no luck with this, any ideas?

Comment: I have created a users view and added a 'Data Export' display which I didn't notice I could do previously. This means I have a page which displays all users and a button to export all users to csv. Is it possible to link directly to the csv export from within the admin area rather than having to create a page?

Comment: Not that I know of off the top of my head. Have a read about adding items to the config page - http://drupal.org/node/206761